# Softmax over time calculation function?

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I have some code that calculate the Softmax over time, but I can't understand a line. Are there anyone can explain for me?

```
    def softmax_over_time(x):
        assert(K.ndim(x) > 2)
        e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))
        s = K.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        return e / s
```

Anyone can explain to me why we use "x - K.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)"?
I think the true must be "K.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)"?

Comment: what, why would softmax always use the max value?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong! Thank for comment

Answer (score 0):

This is to prevent data overflow, for example:

If your output is 1000.0, the calculated exp is inf.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.exp(1000.0))
inf
```

If your output is -1000.0, the calculated exp is 0.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.exp(-1000.0))
0.0
```

But if we subtract a maximum,  there will be no problem.